# Bind click event to the button which has the specific class in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

As per the requirement I have to log the user event click action  of the all the button which has the specific class, to achieve this need to be bind the click event to all the buttons also same function has to be triggered from all the components.

How do I achieve this.

Going to use materialize button.

Comment: The concerned buttons must have a class in common or it could be a directive ?

Comment: Please put some codes for understanding and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directive with selector by that class and listen for clicks:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '.i-watch-clicks'
})
class MyClickBinder
    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event){
        console.info('clicked: ' + $event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for you solution.